# What is the function of the metal mesh in the rubber grommet for the showerhead?

Tags: shower, water-pressure, bathroom-fixtures

Our previous showerhead literally came apart in my hands, so I bought and installed a new one today.

The first grommet connecting the ball joint to the shower pipe has a metal mesh disc in the middle. I assume its purpose is to act as a filter for sediment before anything gets in the fancy shower head and hose. Is this, in fact, it's purpose?

I have a whole home filtration unit, is the mesh necessary in my case? Hypothetically, would removing the mesh increase the overall water pressure out of the shower head?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct. The mesh is there to collect the larger sediment. I would still use it as the pipes could still have sediment and build up and possibly rust, that could pass onto the shower, even in a filtered water system. Extra precautions!!! It doesn't hurt to use it. The rubber part also acts as a gasket/seal. No water leak...or less of one!

Comment: thanks. I wasn't talking about removing the whole grommet, just the mesh...

Answer (score 1):

> I assume its purpose is to act as a filter... Is this, in fact, it's purpose?

YES, but it may also be serving as a gasket. Remove it and reassemble to check for leaks, to confirm whether the rubber part (with or without the mesh) is needed.

> is the mesh necessary in my case?

It depends on your water quality and plumbing type/condition. You seem to be capable of disassembling the shower head so if debris were to cause decreased performance in the future, you could just take it apart and clean out the debris.

> would removing the mesh increase the... pressure out of the shower head?

What you probably are seeking is increased **flow**, not pressure. Removing restrictions would actually *decrease the pressure*. An example would be when you put your thumb over the end of your garden hose, reducing the flow; this increases the back-pressure within the hose, causing the reduced water flow from the end of the hose to come out at a higher pressure. When you remove your thumb, flow increases but pressure drops.

The flow will increase only if the filter itself is significantly contributing to the restriction. Many modern shower heads are designed specifically to reduce flow; in some locales it is mandated by government regulations. Oftentimes the primary restriction is small water passage(s) that can be drilled larger by the end user, or the actual spray nozzles are restrictions.