# What is the role of this contraption that came with the shower hose?

Tags: shower, plumbing-fixture

A replacement shower hose I bought contained the contraption you see below. It seems more intricate than the wire mesh described in [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/117073/what-is-the-function-of-the-metal-mesh-in-the-rubber-grommet-for-the-showerhead) question.  What is its purpose, how does it work, and how shall it be used? If it is to be inserted as part of the hose, in which end of the hose does it need to be inserted and in which direction shall it face?  The hose came with gaskets at both ends.  Is it inserted between the gasket and the hose or between the gasket and the fixture/showerhead?

[image: shower hose contraption]

Comment: Good point! It came in a blister package with no instructions https://www.sdstore.gr/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/%CE%A3%CE%A0%CE%99%CE%A1%CE%91%CE%9B-%CE%9D%CE%95%CE%A1%CE%9F%CE%A7%CE%A5%CE%A4%CE%97-%CE%A7%CE%A1%CE%A9%CE%9C%CE%95-INTERFLEX-1.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Flow restrictor, or regulators, are used to limit the maximum flow output go the shower heads and bidet nozzles on which they are installed.
>
> Flow regulators or restrictors are used in faucets, kitchen sprays, showerheads and shower hand sprays to meet general code and standard requirements, and save water and energy without sacrificing comfort of use. They can be inserted directly into a faucet, kitchen spray or showerhead or as an integral component of our PCA® aerator line.
>
> Installation
>
> The flow restrictor must be installed so that the direction of the water flow was as shown below ; the side of the restrictor with the black rubber ring must face the incoming flow of water.
>
> WARNING: If the flow restrictor is not installed in this manner, the flow of water will dislodge the black rubber ring and will damage the restrictor.

[image]

Picture Source (Screen shot to include photo): https://www.tricontinental.asia/product-details/neoperl-flow-restrictor/

Comment: Oh, that's cute. The flow rate can be changed by changing to a thinner or thicker O-ring.

Comment: The flow rate can also be changed by removing the restrictor entirely!

Comment: BTW- This is, effectively, a link-only answer to anyone who can't see well. The text in the image needs to be quoted in the answer itself for those who need screen readers.

Comment: "Without compromising comfort of use". I suppose that part is debatable...

Comment: I use a variable flow restrictor.  It's called a faucet.

Comment: Interesting that the linked page also includes: "Common flow restrictor used in hotels" so it appears that the OP may have a commercial shower head, not a residential one. No real problem with that, but it's handy to remember for future repairs.